# Find an inactive gameObject with tag?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Is there a way to find inactive gameObjects with a tag? There are answers saying no its not possible but that was in 2013. Any recent changes to do this?

```
 public GameObject[] FindWithTag;

void Update()
{
   FindWithTag = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Player");

    foreach (GameObject FindWithTags in FindWithTag)
    {
     ...
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You still cannot find a disabled object with FindGameObjectsWithTag.

**GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag** - [Manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag.html):

> Returns a list of **active** GameObjects tagged tag. Returns empty array
>   if no GameObject was found.

As a secondary solution you can create an empty enabled object with a tag and then add the disabled object as child of it. Then you can retrieve what you need using [GetComponentInChildren](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponentInChildren.html) (that can find components also on disabled objects).

In that case you can do this:

```
void Update()
{
   FindWithTag = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Player");

    foreach (GameObject FindWithTags in FindWithTag)
    {
         var whatYouNeed = FindWithTags.GetComponentInChildren<YourComponent>(true);
         ...further logic...
    }
}
```

`GetComponentInChildren` can get components also on disabled object if you set its `bool includeInactive` parameter to true (by default it is false).