# How can I register to the event/s if the parent object is first not active when starting the game?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The script :

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SecurityKeypadSystem : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("References")]
    // rather let this class control the display text
    [SerializeField] private TextMesh _text;

    [Header("Settings")]
    // also rather let this class control the length of a code
    [SerializeField] private int _codeLength = 8;

    [Header("Debugging")]
    [SerializeField] private GameObject[] _keyPadNumbers;
    [SerializeField] private List<int> _code = new List<int>();

    // This will be invoked once the code length has reached the target length
    public event Action<int> OnCodeComplete;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    private void Start()
    {
        _keyPadNumbers = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Keypad");

        // register a callback to each key that handles the numbers
        foreach (var keyPadNumber in _keyPadNumbers)
        {
            // It is save to remove an event even if it hasn't been added yet
            // this makes sure it is only added exactly once
            // only adding this here for the case you later have to move this again to Update for some reason ;)
            var securityKeypadKeys = keyPadNumber.GetComponent<SecurityKeypadKeys>();
            securityKeypadKeys.onKeyPressed -= HandleKeyPressed;
            securityKeypadKeys.onKeyPressed += HandleKeyPressed;
            securityKeypadKeys.onKeyPressed += SecurityKeypadKeys_onKeyPressed;
        }
    }

    private void SecurityKeypadKeys_onKeyPressed(int value)
    {
        string gethere = "";
    }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        // just for completeness you should always remove callbacks as soon as they are not needed anymore
        // in order to avoid any exceptions
        foreach (var keyPadNumber in _keyPadNumbers)
        {
            var securityKeypadKeys = keyPadNumber.GetComponent<SecurityKeypadKeys>();
            securityKeypadKeys.onKeyPressed -= HandleKeyPressed;
        }
    }

    // this is called when a keypad key was pressed
    private void HandleKeyPressed(int value)
    {
        // add the value to the list
        _code.Add(value);

        _text.text += value.ToString();

        // Check if the code has reached the target length
        // if not do nothing
        if (_code.Count < _codeLength) return;

        // if it reached the length combine all numbers into one int
        var exponent = _code.Count;
        float finalCode = 0;
        foreach (var digit in _code)
        {
            finalCode =digit * Mathf.Pow(10, exponent);
            exponent--;
        }

        // invoke the callback event
        OnCodeComplete?.Invoke((int)finalCode);

        // and reset the code
        ResetCode();
    }

    // Maybe you later want an option to clear the code field from the outside as well
    public void ResetCode()
    {
        _code.Clear();
        _text.text = "";
    }

    // also clear the input if this gets disabled
    private void OnDisable()
    {
        ResetCode();
    }
}
```

Inside the Start I'm making this line :

```
_keyPadNumbers = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Keypad");
```

but this return 0 because when I'm running the game the GameObjects that have the tag "keypad" are not active yet they are getting active later in the game.

Here is  screenshot of the GameObject with this script attached to it and the Key Cubes gameobjects that are not active :

[image: Security System]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find an inactive gameObject with tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57323175/find-an-inactive-gameobject-with-tag)

Comment: Since you're just wiring up event handlers on those `SecurityKeypadKeys` objects in `Start`, I would instead have each of those `SecurityKeypadKeys` objects fire an event in `Start` or `OnEnable`, and then have `SecurityKeypadSystem` respond to those events by wiring up the event handlers on the key.